# Passing parameters in BODY with GET request

Tags: rest, get, restify

I want to pass some data within request body, but I'm using GET request, because I just want to modify this data and send it back.

I know that it is bad practice to use body with GET requests.

But what should I do with this situation if I want to build correct RESTful service?

P.S. I'm not changin any object on server. 
I'm not putting any new object on server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061).

Comment: Can you provide more specifics? You almost certainly should be using POST.

Comment: I want to pass some string to GET resource and return some hash of this string. The string can be a bit huge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `POST`. Something like

```
POST /hashes
{
    "myInput": ...
}
```

The response would be the hashed value. There's no rule that the created resource must be retained by the server.

From the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5):

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a
> resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200
> (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status,
> depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that
> describes the result.